# What does "for" mean in Psalm 25:11?

Tags: hebrew, word-study, grammar

> [Psalm 25:11](https://biblehub.com/psalms/25-11.htm) For thy name's sake, O LORD, pardon mine iniquity;
>   **for** it is great.

What is the meaning of **for** in this verse? which word can be substituted instead of **for** to get the most accurate meaning. Let me give 2 suggestions.

1. For thy name's sake, O LORD, pardon mine iniquity;
   **because** it is great.
2. For thy name's sake, O LORD, pardon mine iniquity;
       **which** it is great.

This question has a background which is the answer given by [b a](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/21321/b-a) in [What does the word “for” mean and imply in Psalms 18:17?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/38191/what-does-the-word-for-mean-and-imply-in-psalms-1817/38192?noredirect=1#comment74559_38192)

Comment: כִּי Prepositional prefix, I don’t think it carries the amount of weight you are affording it but maybe I’m wrong. Certainly I don’t currently don’t see it that way

Comment: @MrConstantin—כִּי is not a [prepositional prefix in Hebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefixes_in_Hebrew).

Comment: That’s true it’s the full form of a prepositional prefix or a primitive particle, consequently used as an adverb or conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

כִּי is yet again causal and is perhaps best understood as “because” or “since.”

According to Franz Delitzsch,<sup>1</sup>

> כִּי gives **the ground** of the need and urgency of the petition.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Delitzsch, p. [344](https://archive.org/details/biblicalcommenta05keil05/page/n359)

#### References

Delitzsch, Franz. [*Commentary on the Old Testament.*](https://archive.org/details/biblicalcommenta05keil05/) 1900. Reprint. Trans. Bolton, Francis. Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 1988.

Comment: I would also like the comment/answer of @ba

Answer (score 0):

Here is a capture from Bible Hub for this word, "for".
[image: https://biblehub.com/psalms/25-11.htm]

There is a wonderful expression of God's grace here by David.  He is pleading forgiveness because God is who He is - kind, merciful and forgiving.  Further, it is urgent because David's sin is so great.  It reminds me of Paul's remark in Rom 5:20, "... But where sin increased, grace increased all the more".

Comment: I read a [sermon by Jonahan Edwards](http://www.biblebb.com/files/edwards/je-pardon.htm) based on the same way of interpretation but @ba gave a different meaning to _for_ in another verse. So I was curious.